# EF returns old values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm

I'm using EF6 + WPF with MVVM design pattern in my desktop application. I'm using also Autofac as DI container.

I read a lot about EF context lifetime management and I decided to have only one instane of EF context for single view model instance. I found several interesting articles about that approach, so I thought that it is only good way to manage EF context. I use Autofac to manage EF lifetime, so every time I create new view model, there will be created only one new EF context.

But of course, I came across a problem. Most of my EF queries work good, but the following query always returns old (cached) value. I call this query every time I push 'Execute' button, so there are many executions per single view / view model

```
this.context.someTable.Where(arg => arg.value == "value").Single();
```

I know that I can always reload the entity with following code

```
this.context.Entry(entity).Reload();
```

But for me it is not a good solution. I know also that if I dispose current context and recreate before next query I will always receive current values. But this approach conflicts with one context per one view model approach.

What should I fix / change to avoid EF caching issues and still have good performance.

Comment: Is someTable part of the said MVVM controller? Or is this controller reading data from another table? I suspect you are opening this window, changing the data in another window, and then not seeing the data updated in this window. We need clarification of the context of that DB Read statement, and the relevance of someTable.

Comment: I try to separate MVVM logic from DB structure, so very often single MVVM reads data from multiple tables. I don use EF enties in MVVM layer, instead of that I use bussiness objects / model objects. My current problem is about saving new business object to db. I have to calculate some index (it is not db index) based on current value of `var entity = this.context.someTable.Where(arg => arg.value == "value").Single();` After that I have to update `entity` (increment). Of course if another user in another app will do the same, then EF context will return old `entity` (due to EH caching )

Comment: @Todd has given you the answer: you can't realistically expect a long-lived EF context to know that another user, in their own context, in a different app, on a different PC, has modified an entity that it is currently tracking. *Unless* you reload, which will cause your context to go back to db and, well, reload. But you don't want to do that for some reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You shouldn't persist a context**

I would recommend you abandon the single shared context. I did this recently for a large WPF application. An EF context is designed to be a unit-of-work, you should use it and then call `.Dispose()`. If you need to read in relationship properties eagerly, you should use `.Include()` hints. You should construct your contexts in a `using` block so you know where you lose scope, and to ensure the context is disposed.

You will find that performance of EF can actually diminish as it needs to refer to its internal cache and state. I have found bulk data insert patterns deteriorate if a shared context is used. EF doesn't perform as well as an RDBMS.

As you have experienced, you can persist the context and benefit from cached entities, but if that's becoming a pain, due to the nature of your system and requirements of the user, you are not really benefiting from the caching anymore.  Your backing RDBMS should be fast enough. As soon as you cache in any way (including EF second-level caching and ASP.NET Output Caching), you immediately need to plan how to expire your cached entities. This adds a lot more work for your coders, and gives your systems spectacular new ways to fail.

For instance, consider that a benefit of EF is the automatic resolution of relationship properties. You can be seamlessly reaching across a graph of data until you hit an entity which is cached and stale. In such circumstances, it is difficult to expire the cache before retrieving such entities.

**But if you must reload on Update**

If you really don't want to change your architecture to the Microsoft recommended/intended way. I suggest you keep track of all open contexts (adding to static collection on construction, removing on dispose, double-check with finalizer pattern, and finalizer suppression on dispose), and implement some generic code in the save pipeline (there are a few ways of doing this) which attempts to reload the entity across all open contexts. This is an proactive way of expiring your EF entity caches. This may affect performance on larger collections, but you could have a whitelist or blacklist of entities to process, rather than processing all saved entities.

Personally, I'm glad I made the change (restructuring to short-lived contexts), long term there are huge benefits in terms of code maintainability and system stability.

Answer (score 7):

Following method forces EF to requery the query to the database and do not cache the result:

```
this.context.someTable.AsNoTracking().Where(arg => arg.value == "value").Single();
```

The important method call is [AsNoTracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: `AsNoTracking` doesn't resolve my issue, because I want to modify entity and if I add `AsNoTracking` no records will be updated.

Comment: Ah, ok. But why do you dispose the DBContext during livetime of the viewmodel?

Comment: I dont dispose. I have the same context as long as viewmodel lives. So during few operations dbcontext has some cached entieties and thats why it returns old values

Answer (score 0):

If you use MVVM then you can do: your view bind to your view model with property type EntityViewModel (is a wrapper for the Entity). All changes immediately appear in the EntityViewModel. If you want to undo changes - invoke method EntityViewModel.Undo(). If you want to apply the changes to the entity - invoke EntityViewModel.Apply(). Then you can invoke method DbContext.SaveChanges().

```
public class Entity 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class EntityViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _state;

    public EntityViewModel(Entity entity)
    {
        Entity = entity;
        _state = entity.State;
    }

    public string State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _state)
                return;
            _state = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("State");
        }
    }

    public Entity Entity {get; private set; }

    public void ApplyChanges()
    {
        Entity.State = _state;
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
        State = entity.State;
    }
}
```

This is a good division of responsibilities, which fits into the MVVM.

Comment: Add what if user in another instance of application loads the same entity and changes it? First application will dont know that entity has been changed until sb will call context.SaveChanges().

Comment: I did not understand your question. If you have a issue: loading entity -> modify entity state -> get same entity not modify state then you can use what I suggested or use: context.Entry(modifyEntity).OriginalValues - this returns the original data without resorting to the database.

Comment: if you want to periodically do refresh entity (because it could change in another application) then in any case you will have to access the database. In this case, this.context.Entry(entity).Reload() - a good option.

Comment: Also, you can not periodically refresh entity. Instead, use optimistic offline lock (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/optimisticOfflineLock.html).

Comment: My question is not about need of refreshing object but concept of keeping the same db context for the whole lifetime of view model. Furthermore I dont see any pros of using EF cache, because every time EF uses cache instead of going to db there always be situation where cache will store old values.