# Extracting rows from DB after Saving changes using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm

I am struggiling with unexpected behavior in EntityFramework.
At first I display some data from DB on my screen. There is a possibility to modify this data. After I modify this data I SaveChangesAsync in DB (and they are there - I have checked in SQL Manager). And displayed data is OK until refresh, because then data displayed is right from before changes.

After await UnitOfWork.Complete (DBEntities context.SaveChangesAsync) I run DbSet.Where(predicates) and it returns old values.

I can provide some code if you need, just say what as there is plenty of it. Or ask me questions about what I did - I'll try to put it here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF returns old values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042161/ef-returns-old-values)

Comment: I needed to reload my context. I have voted to set as duplicate for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042161/ef-returns-old-values It actually helped me. I couldn't figure out how to ask the question, but maybe this will help other to reach above question :)